# How to create a Clone based on a previous state of the Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, point-in-time

I need to create a clone of an Azure storage account based on a particular time (not the latest). The source storage account won't be rollbacked to the particular time and make a clone of it. I need the source storage account be remain as it is and make a clone on a previous state of the storage account.

*Example:*

I need to make a clone of the **storage account A** which was at the state of **yesterday 1.00pm**, to **storage account B**

[image]

- Point-in-time restore doesn't work here cause I don't want to
  rollback my source storage account.

Comment: You've specified what you *need*, but not what you've *tried* and what you ran into trying to solve your requirement that way. Please refer to [ask]. On-topic: have you looked at [Point-in-time restore for block blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-overview)?

Comment: I've looked on point-in-time-restore. It's not working with this case.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this feature is not available in Azure Storage. There's a point-in-time restore feature and also there's an object replication feature but both of them will not work in your scenario as per my understanding.

**Point-in-time restore** will restore the blobs based on a restore point. However it will only restore the blobs in the same account. Restoring blobs in a separate storage account is not supported today. You can learn more about this feature here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-overview.

**Object replication** feature will asynchronously copy the blobs from one storage account to another but you cannot specify a restore point. Only thing you could specify is the creation time of the blob. You can learn more about this feature here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/object-replication-overview.

Comment: Yes @Gaurav. I tried both features and those didn't match with this scenario. Thank you.